# Is there a way to open a tab within an iframe with a different web browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

Some things in pages can't run on certain web browsers it seems. Soccer Physics is a game on `ottoojala.com/soccerphysics` and it doesn't run on chrome, saying it needs internet explorer.

Is there any way in which I can run this page on internet explorer using an iframe within chrome. What I mean by this is can I get the functionality of internet explorer into an iframe on chrome?

Any suggesetions can help.

Thanks.

Comment: NOT, only same browser.

Comment: ok thanks, I guess I can't put it in my page XD

Comment: See https://www.browserstack.com/